# how to block advertisement popups in web browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, popups

I use Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome as web browsers. But when i open it, a lot of unwanted advertisement pop ups and other windows would be opened.To close each and every pop ups and windows is a  ridiculous and time consuming  job.It makes my system slow. I tried to block it by blocking pop ups , plug ins and java scripts.   If i block these pop ups....in some necessary situations (internet banking,railway ticket booking...) it will give me a negative result.I have given some exceptions (bank website) in pop ups blocking.Still the problem exists. How can i overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many addons available e.g. 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ad blocking extension for both Chrome and Firefox, like AdBlock Plus.
https://adblockplus.org/

Edit: They block only ads popups, not legit ones

Answer (score 0):

Well you really can't. The default popup blocker of chrome does a pretty good job, but it lets some through. You use a dedicated popup blocker and it will block necessary popups like those of banks. The only solution is to either live with some popups, or use dedicated one and resort to whitelisting.