# How to block ad popups in web browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, adblock

Current web browsers (firefox, chrome, ...) usually have built in popup blockers that prevent popups appearing without user interaction (click on link).

In addition, there are multiple addons that usually do a good job at preventing unwanted adds/popups (adblock plus, adblock plus popup addon, ...).

However I have recently faced a new way of opening a popup that seems to be poorly handled by web browsers/add ons:

Option 1:
the user clicks on a link (in tab1), the link opens in the current tab (tab1), and a javascript script tries to open a popup (in tab2).

Option2:
the user clicks on a link (in tab1), the link opens in a new tab (tab2), and a javascript script tries to open an ad in the origin tab (tab1).

The option1 seems to be well handled by browsers, but the option2 doesn't.
Any idea how to block the second option ?

Comment: What sites do this?  And what are you using for adblocking currently?

Comment: uBlock Origin ("uBO") supports the filter option `popunder`, to be used for option 2. uBO will automatically tries to detect popunders (option 2) using existing filters with the `popup` filter option, but if this fails, one can always use the `popunder` filter option explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to block advertisement popups in web browser](https://superuser.com/questions/834203/how-to-block-advertisement-popups-in-web-browser)

Answer (score 0):

`NoScript` might sounds like bazooka aproach, but you can find out it stops  a lot of this and other problems.

Homepage https://noscript.net/ defines it as

> The NoScript Firefox extension provides extra protection for Firefox, Seamonkey and other mozilla-based browsers: this free, open source add-on allows JavaScript, Java, Flash and other plugins to be executed only by trusted web sites of your choice (e.g. your online bank).
>   NoScript also provides the most powerful anti-XSS and anti-Clickjacking protection ever available in a browser.
>   NoScript's unique whitelist based pre-emptive script blocking approach prevents exploitation of security vulnerabilities (known and even not known yet!) with no loss of functionality...

by default, it will disable JavaScript from untrusted sites completely (sometimes even replacing it with surrogates so page navigation continues to work), but even for trusted sites with JS enabled it will still offer many different protections.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.